# Is there an easier way to show that the multiplicative norm $N(r+s\sqrt{-n})=r^2+ns^2\neq p$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$?

Tags: ring-theory, normed-spaces, integral-domain

**Context**

Let $n ≥ 3$ be an odd positive integer that is not a perfect square, and let $R =\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{−n}]$, with multiplicative norm $N(r + s\sqrt{−n} ) = r^2 + ns^2$ for every element $r + s\sqrt{−n} ∈ R$.  Let $p ∈ \mathbb{Z}, p ≥ 2$, be a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p$ divides $n + 1$.  $p$ is not prime in $R$.

**Question**

Show that there is no element $r + s\sqrt{−n} ∈ R$, for $r, s ∈ \mathbb{Z}$, with norm equal to $p$.

Hint: determine first which of the two numbers $p$, $n$ is smaller than the
other.

**My answer**

Let $$r^2+ns^2=p$$  $$ns^2=p-r^2$$  $p$ divides $n+1$ therefore $p\leq n+1$ 
$$(p-1)s^2\leq ns^2=p-r^2$$ $$(p-1)s^2\leq p-r^2$$ $$ps^2-s^2\leq p-r^2$$  $$p(s^2-1)\leq s^2-r^2$$  $$2\leq p \leq \frac{s^2-r^2}{s^2-1}$$  $$2(s^2-1)\leq s^2-r^2$$ $$s^2-2\leq -r^2$$  $$s^2+r^2\leq 2$$
Only integer square numbers less than $2$ are $0$ and $1$.  When you sub the 4 combinations of $r^2=0$ or $1$ and $s^2=0$ or $1$ into $r^2+ns^2$ none of them can be true.  Hence there is no element in $R$, that satisfies $N(r+s\sqrt{-n})=p$.

I believe this to be a satisfactory answer to the question, but it felt very long winded.  Is there a shorter way?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p=2,$ we have $n \geq 3$ so $p < n.$

Otherwise,
$n+1$ is even but $p$ is odd. So $p \neq n+1.$ in fact, as $p$ is a divisor, $p \leq (n+1)/ 2$ and $p < n.$

detail: we are told $p$ divides $n+1.$ In both cases, $p \neq n+1.$ There is some integer $q$ with $pq=n+1.$ As $p \neq n+1,$ we get $q \neq 1$ and $q \geq 2.$ So $n+1 = pq \geq 2p.$

If we assume we have $r^2 + n s^2 = p,$ this shows $s = 0.$ But then $r^2 = p$ in the ordinary integers, while $p$ is prime. Contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  How do we know $p$ is odd, could it not be 2?  Though we could always rule out the individual case of $2$ pretty easily I imagine regardless.

Comment: @mike edited  ...

Comment: How do we know that $p\leq (n+1)/2$?  Is it not possible for $(n+1)/2\leq p\leq n+1?$  Also, does $p<n$ make $s=0$ because you are comparing it to a $0n$ on the right side of the equation?  Sorry for making you be so explicit, I just want to make sure I understand it fully.

Comment: Thank for taking the time to add detail and answer my question!